# Executing processes in vb.net with a delay

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm trying to execute a number of processes from a listview although i need a delay between them.

My vb.net knowledge is limited,

```
 For Each ListView1 As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.Items

                If ListView1.Checked = True Then
                    Dim targetName As String = ListView1.SubItems(5).Text.ToString
                    Dim fileExists As Boolean

                    fileExists = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(targetName)
                    If fileExists = True Then
                        Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process
                        p = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
                        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\"
                        p.StartInfo.FileName = URLDecode(targetName)
                        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                        p.Start()
                        p.Close()
                    Else
```

This will execute the processes fine most of the time, which is actually an mp3 file and it will add it to winamps playlist. Sometimes it just fires too quickly and it's causing winamp to crash while processing the mp3's, how can i put in a delay between executing each process without locking up the ui?  Also any suggestions on how i can improve the overall code and make it more stable would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Threading

Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

`Thread.Sleep()` takes a number of miliseconds to wait, so the above will wait 5 seconds.

Comment: will that not freeze the ui?